# R loop for anova on multiple files

Tags: r, loops, anova

I would like to execute `anova` on multiple datasets stored in my working directory.  I have come up so far with:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
for (i in seq_along(files)) {
    mydataset.i <- files[i]
    AnovaModel.1 <- aov(DES ~ DOSE, data=mydataset.i)
    summary(AnovaModel.1)
}
```

As you can see I am very new to loops and cannot make this work. I also understand that I need to add a code to append all summary outputs in one file. I would appreciate any help you can provide to guide to the working loop that can execute anovas on multiple .csv files in the directory (same headers) and produce outputs for the record.

Comment: I would like to capture all the output. My output typically looks like a typical anova table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to use `list.files` with `full.names = TRUE` in case you are not on the same path.

```
files <- list.files("path_to_my_dir", pattern="*.csv", full.names = T)
# use lapply to loop over all files
out <- lapply(1:length(files), function(idx) {
    # read the file
    this.data <- read.csv(files[idx], header = TRUE) # choose TRUE/FALSE accordingly
    aov.mod <- aov(DES ~ DOSE, data = this.data)
    # if you want just the summary as object of summary.aov class
    summary(aov.mod)
    # if you require it as a matrix, comment the previous line and uncomment the one below
    # as.matrix(summary(aov.mod)[[1]])
})
head(out)
```

This should give you a `list` with each entry of the list having a `summary matrix` in the *same order* as the input file list.

Comment: Thank you, I can run the script without any errors (using Rstudio) but I do not see the output in the Console.

Comment: everything runs great until the 'head(out)'. I get: '   
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"}
head"'

Comment: You are right, the code is working great. I get my ANOVA summaries in the console window, I just need to work to output it in the text file. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Hi Arun, I am trying to modify the script by adding multiple models to it. For example another aov.mod.1 <- aov(DES ~ DOSE, data = this.data) and another summary(aov.mod.1). Running the script I do not get any errors but only get summaries of summary(aov.mod) - the first output that the function produces. Could you please direct me to the "strategy" of having multiple outcomes recorded with one function. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that your loop is not loading your data. Your list of file names is in "files" then you start moving through that list and set mydataset.i equal to the name of the file that matches your itterator i... but then you try to run aov on the file name that is stored in mydataset.i!

The command you are looking for to redirect your output to a file is sink. Consider the following:

```
sink("FileOfResults.txt") #starting the redirect to the file
files <- list.files("path_to_my_dir", pattern="*.csv", full.names = T) #using the fuller code from Arun
for (i in seq_along(files)){
   mydataset.i <- files[i]
   mydataset.d <- read.csv(mydataset.i) #this line is new
   AnovaModel.1 <- aov(DES ~ DOSE, data=mydataset.d) #this line is modified
   print(summary(AnovaModel.1))
} 
sink() #ending the redirect to the file
```

I prefer this approach to Arun's because the results are stored directly to the file without jumping through a list and then having to figure out how to store the list to a file in a readable fashion.

Comment: Thank you, this looks really clean and I seem to understand the idea behind the code. I do get the FileOfResluts.txt file in my working directory and no additional error. However, the "FileOfResults.txt" is blank/empty. Is it possible that I need to employ print command to create the output?

Comment: Interesting. Quite possibly... You may need to wrap your summary function call with print.

Comment: Yes, print was required,  I have modified the script to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful and educational.